# Getting "Cannot call a class as a function" in my React Project

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I'm trying to add a React map component to my project but run into an error. I'm using Fullstack React's [blog post](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/#the-map-container-component) as a reference. I tracked down where the error gets thrown in google_map.js line 83:

```
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { 
  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { 
    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); 
    } 
  }
```

Here is my map component so far. The page loads just fine (without a map) when I comment out lines 58-60, the last three lines. edit: I made the changes that @Dmitriy Nevzorov suggested and it still gives me the same error.

```
import React from 'react'
import GoogleApiComponent from 'google-map-react'

export class LocationsContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
  render() {
    const style = {
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh'
    }
    return (
      <div style={style}>
        <Map google={this.props.google} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export class Map extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        if (prevProps.google !== this.props.google){
            this.loadMap();
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.loadMap();
    }
    loadMap(){
        if (this.props && this.props.google){
            const {google} = this.props;
            const maps = google.maps;

            const mapRef = this.refs.map;
            const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(mapRef);

            let zoom = 14;
            let lat = 37.774929
            let lng = 122.419416
            const center = new maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            const mapConfig = Object.assign({}, {
                center: center,
                zoom: zoom
            })
            this.map = new maps.Map(node, mapConfig)
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref='map'>
                Loading map...
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default GoogleApiComponent({
  apiKey: MY_API_KEY
})(LocationsContainer)
```

And here is where this map component gets routed in main.js:

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import Artists from './components/Artists'
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import Home from './components/HomePage'
import Gallery from './components/ArtGallery'
import ArtistPage from './components/ArtistPage'
import FavsPage from './components/FavsPage'
import LocationsContainer from './components/Locations'

//Create the route configuration
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="locations" component={LocationsContainer} />
        <Route path="artists" component={Artists} /> 
        <Route path="gallery" component={Gallery} />     
      <Route path="favorites" component={FavsPage} />
      <Route path=":artistName" component={ArtistPage} />
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: You have two `export default`s, and would it be `new GoogleAPIComponent()` not `GoogleAPIComponent()`?

Comment: I removed one of the defaults and tried your suggestion. It looks like it is actually talking to Google Maps now, which is good, but before the page can load it throws another cryptic error: Locations.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function". 

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you remove the `(LocationContainer)`?

Comment: Thanks, I think that got it! Weird, that's how they have it written on their blog post. 

Still getting a few other errors from Google Maps, I'll put them here:
'GoogleMap: apiKey is deprecated, use bootstrapURLKeys={{key: YOUR_API_KEY}} instead. google_map.js:689
GoogleMap: center or defaultCenterproperty must be defined google_map.js:699
GoogleMap: zoom or defaultZoomproperty must be defined google_map.js: 704'

Comment: I'm not sure about the other errors, but you could try this to fix the first one: `export default new GoogleApiComponent({ bootstrapURLKeys: MY_API_KEY })`

Comment: Thanks, that took care of that. I ran into more issues with this repo not being able to mesh well with the existing project and the API so I scrapped it and used [React-Gmap](https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/react-gmaps) instead. I spent about a day using this repo and within an hour I had the other up and running. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Check that you're missing `new` when trying to initiate a class

Answer (score 228):

For me it happened when I forgot to write `extends React.Component` at the end.
I know it's not exactly what YOU had, but others reading this answer can benefit from this, hopefully.

Comment: There's great post at overreacted that explains why this works https://overreacted.io/how-does-react-tell-a-class-from-a-function/

Comment: Summary of post: Distinguishing between a class and a function in browser is actually not completely trivial ... "The actual solution is really simple, but \[I'm going on a\] huge tangent to explain why React ended up with this solution ..." blah, blah, blah, ... -> "If you don’t extend React.Component, React won’t find isReactComponent on the prototype, and won’t treat component as a class."

Comment: Great. I was facing the similar issue & your solution fixed the issue. But my syntax was `import React, { Component } from 'react'; class extends Component`. I couldn't understand how did this resolve the issue by replacing `Component` with `React.Component`. Does the import matters?

Answer (score 116):

For me it was because I forgot to use the `new` keyword when setting up Animated state.

eg:

`fadeAnim: Animated.Value(0),`

to

`fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),`

would fix it.

---

**Edit from 5 years on with more explanation:**

The most likely issue is that you're missing the `new` keyword somewhere, just like I did above. What this means is you don't even need to be using React to come across this error.

The issue is that in JS you can create classes like so (Example from MDN):

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }

}
```

If you wanted to use this class, you need to create a *new instance* of it like so:

```js
const rect = new Rect(height, width);
```

The reason for this problem is often you're trying to do a function call to the *definition* of the class (or something inside the definition), rather than an *instance* of the class.

Essentially, in code, you're doing this:

```js
Rectangle.calcArea() // incorrect!
```

when you should be doing

```js
rect.calcArea() // correct!
```

Comment: This solved my problem, I was using a different use case not the animated but after using the new keyword solved it.
Thank you

Comment: Spent 4 hours 44 minutes and 4 seconds trying to know wth happened. You are god.

Comment: Yup, that was me too. Thank you!

Comment: Does someone know in which version it changed? (another thing to worry about RN)

Comment: The same exact thing happened to me, and I mean Exact (down to the variable name).  Creepy...

Comment: After crawling all over the place in a vain attempt to resolve my problem, this simple fix was wot dun it for me (Brits will understand that)! Thank you so much! I was going spare! Incidentally, my issue was with a plan vanilla script. I don't use React so your solution may work in other contexts too.

Comment: @ThomasMurphy Glad to help! You're absolutely right. It has been 5 years since I answered this question, and I understand the issue more now. 

The most common cause for this issue will be that you've missed `new` keyword somewhere. By using the `new` keyword, you're creating an instance of a class, rather than referencing the class itself.

Answer (score 66):

### tl;dr

If you use React Router v4 check your `<Route/>` component if you indeed use the `component` prop to pass your class based React component!

More generally: If your class seems ok, check if the code that calls it doesn't try to use it as a function.

### Explanation

I got this error because I was using React Router v4 and I accidentally used the `render` prop instead of the `component` one in the `<Route/>` component to pass my component that was a class. This was a problem, because `render` expects (calls) a function, while `component` is the one that will work on React components.

So in this code:

```
<HashRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" render={MyComponent} />
    </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

The line containing the `<Route/>` component, should have been written like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={MyComponent} />
```

It is a shame, that they don't check it and give a usable error for such and easy to catch mistake.

Answer (score 52):

Happened to me because I used

`PropTypes.arrayOf(SomeClass)`

instead of

`PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.instanceOf(SomeClass))`

Comment: Thanks, wrong PropTypes definition was the issue in my case.

Comment: this solved my issue! was `PropTypes.oneOfType([SomeClass, SomeOtherClass]).isRequired,` instead of  `PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.instanceOf(SomeClass), PropTypes.instanceOf(SomeOtherClass)]).isRequired,`

Comment: Thanks, was really wondering for a long time what was going wrong there!

Answer (score 17):

For me, it was `ComponentName.prototype` instead of `ComponentName.propTypes`.
auto suggested by `Phpstorm` IDE. Hope it will help someone.

Comment: yeah this happen to me

Answer (score 16):

I experienced the same issue, it occurred because my `ES6` component class was not extending `React.Component`.

Answer (score 15):

You have duplicated `export default` declaration. The first one get overridden by second one which is actually a function.

Comment: Good catch! I left the default in front of GoogleApiComponent and I still get the same error. Alternatively, removing all defaults gives me an "unexpected token" error in my terminal on GoogleApiComponent.

Answer (score 8):

Mostly these issues occur when you miss extending **Component** from react:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class TimePicker extends Component {
    render() {
        return();     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For me it was because i used prototype instead of **propTypes**

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

 render() {
    return <div>Test</div>;
  }
}

MyComponent.prototype = {

};
```

it ought to be

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {

};
```

Comment: Exact same case for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
Post.proptypes = {

}
```

to

```
Post.propTypes = {

}
```

someone should comment on how to monitor such error in a very precise way.

Comment: It is better to explain your solution/answer with some detailed information.

Comment: Yaah it happens, Bravo !

Answer (score 6):

Two things you can check is,

```
class Slider extends React.Component {
    // Your React Code
}

Slider.propTypes = {
    // accessibility: PropTypes.bool,
}
```

- Make sure that you extends **React.Component**
- Use **propTypes** instead of prototype (as per IDE intellisense)

Comment: should be Slider.propTypes: { }

Answer (score 5):

This is a general issue, and doesn't appear in a single case. But, the common problem in all the cases is that you forget to `import` a specific component (doesn't matter if it's either from a library that you installed or a custom made component that you created):

`import {SomeClass} from 'some-library'`

When you use it later, without importing it, the compiler thinks it's a function. Therefore, it breaks. This is a common example:

**`imports`**

**`...code...`**

and then somewhere inside your code

**`<Image {..some props} />`**

If you forgot to import the component `<Image />` then the compiler will not complain like it does for other imports, but will break when it reaches your code.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there're no single case when this error appears.

Happened to me when I didn't declare constructor in statefull component.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return <div>Test</div>;
    }
}
```

instead of

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Test</div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In file `MyComponent.js`

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
...
}
```

I put some function related to that component:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
...
}

export myFunction() {
...
}
```

and then in another file imported that function:

```
import myFunction from './MyComponent'
...
myFunction() // => bang! "Cannot call a class as a function"
...
```

Can you spot the problem?

I forgot the curly braces, and imported `MyComponent` under name `myFunction`!

So, the fix was:

```
import {myFunction} from './MyComponent'
```

Answer (score 2):

I received this error by making small mistake. My error was exporting the class as a function instead of as a class. At the bottom of my class file I had:

```
export default InputField();
```

**when it should have been:**

```
export default InputField;
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was because I'd accidentally deleted my `render` method !

I had a class with a `componentWillReceiveProps` method I didn't need anymore, immediately preceding a short `render` method.  In my haste removing it, I accidentally removed the entire `render` method as well.

This was a *PAIN* to track down, as I was getting console errors pointing at comments in completely irrelevant files as being the "source" of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem I was calling the render method incorrectly

Gave an error:

```
render = () => {
    ...
}
```

instead of

correct:

```
render(){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had it when I did so :

```
function foo() (...) export default foo
```

correctly:

```
export default  () =>(...);
```

or

```
const foo = ...
export default foo
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it happened because I didn't wrap my connect function properly, and tried to export default two components

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error when I imported the wrong *class* and referred to wrong *store* while using mobx in react-native.

**I faced error in this snippet :**

```
import { inject, Observer } from "mobx-react";

@inject ("counter")
@Observer
```

**After few corrections like as below snippet. I resolved my issue like this way.**

```
import { inject, observer } from "mobx-react";

@inject("counterStore")
@observer
```

What was actually wrong,I was using the wrong class instead of `observer` I used `Observer` and instead of `counterStore` I used `counter`.  I solved my issue like this way.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this when writing an import statement wrong while importing a function, rather than a class. If `removeMaterial` is a function in another module:

Right:

```
import { removeMaterial } from './ClaimForm';
```

Wrong:

```
import removeMaterial from './ClaimForm';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into this, it is possible you have a javascript error inside of your react component. Make sure if you are using a dependency you are using the `new` operator on the class to instantiate the new instance. Error will throw if

`this.classInstance = Class({})`

instead use

`this.classInstance = new Class({})`

you will see in the error chain in the browser

`at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner`

that is the giveaway I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i wrote `comment` in place of `Component` by mistake

I just wrote this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

  class Something extends Component{
      render() {
          return();
     }
  }
```

Instead of this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

  class Something extends comment{
      render() {
          return();
     }
  }
```

it's not a big deal but for a beginner like me it's really confusing.
I hope this will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using JSX a parent component  was calling other components without the "<>"

```
 <ComponentA someProp={someCheck ? ComponentX : ComponentY} />
```

fix

```
<ComponentA someProp={someCheck ? <ComponentX /> : <ComponentY />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another report here: It didn't work as I exported:

```
export default compose(
  injectIntl,
  connect(mapStateToProps)(Onboarding)
);
```

instead of

```
export default compose(
  injectIntl,
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(Onboarding);
```

Note the position of the brackets. Both are correct and won't get caught by either a linter or prettier or something similar. Took me a while to track it down.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally put component name (`Home`) as the first argument to `connect` function while it was supposed to be at the end. duh.

This one -surely- gave me the error:

```
export default connect(Home)(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

But this one worked -surely- fine:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

Answer (score 0):

This occured when I accidentally named my `render` function incorrectly:

```
import React from 'react';

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  noCalledRender() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello, world!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My instance of this error was simply caused because my class did not have a proper `render` method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all the problem redux connect. solutions:

**Correct**:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PageName)
```

**Wrong & Bug**:

```
export default connect(PageName)(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I was attempting to use hot reloading on a custom hook (not sure why, probably just muscle memory when creating components).

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    return useSelector(
        // Do things
    );
};

// The next line is what breaks it
export default hot(module)(useCustomHook);
```

The correct way

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    return useSelector(
        // Do things
    );
};

export default useCustomHook;
```

Apparently you can't hot reload hook

Answer (score 0):

In my case I accidentally called **objectOf**

```
static propTypes = {
    appStore: PropTypes.objectOf(AppStore).isRequired
}
```

Instead of **instanceOf**:

```
static propTypes = {
    appStore: PropTypes.instanceOf(AppStore).isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution to my problem with this same error.

I made a very silly mistake by using the class `Alert('hi')` directly instead of the function `alert('hi')`.

Fortunately, I found this within an hour. So a lot of time was saved.

Lookout for those class instance use cases where you were supposed to use the functions. This doesn't necessarily need to be in the same class as the one you were modifying. Even if it's present in just one file out of all the files, it will throw the same error.

One way you can find it is by navigating between screens, the error will be thrown when you are on the screen where error exists.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was a wrong import of a reducer in the rootReducer.js. I imported container instead of reducer file.

Example

```
import settings from './pages/Settings';
```

But sure it should be

```
import settings from './pages/Settings/reducer';
```

Where settings directory contains following files actions.js, index.js, reducer.js.

To check it you can log reducers arg of the assertReducerShape() function from the redux/es/redux.js.

Answer (score -2):

If you're on Node JS and you're seeing this error in a Class you've added to support a Cucumber test, it's because Cucumber will automatically try to run anything that exports a function, and NodeJS internally converts a Class to a function.

So instead of this:

```
module.exports = MyClass;
```

do this:

```
module.exports.MyClass = MyClass;
```

Then, when you import it into your steps file, do it like this:

```
let MyClass = require("myclass.js").MyClass;
```

This way you're not exporting a function.  Read more [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/652).