# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, gulp, babeljs

**I have looked through all of the answers on this question:**

[Getting "Cannot call a class as a function" in my React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481857/getting-cannot-call-a-class-as-a-function-in-my-react-project)

---

I am still unable to work out why the below is returning the error *'Cannot call a class as a function'*. Am I missing something here in terms of the syntax?

- I am running through Gulp, Rollup and Babel
- All plugins for above are included
- The selector for reactDOM.render is fine and export of the class is not needed

#### Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div />
        );
    }
}

// Selector is fine, changes bg to red
document.querySelector('#app').style.background = 'red';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

#### Error:

[image]

**Gulp task with Rollup and Babel:**

```
gulp.task('js', () => {

    // Package up ES6 moduleswith stream
    const stream = plugins.rollupStream({
        input: paths.dev + '/script/app.js',
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        plugins: [
            plugins.rollupPluginReplace({'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'production' )}),
            plugins.rollupPluginJsx({ factory: 'React.createElement' }),
            plugins.rollupPluginCommonjs({}),           
            plugins.rollupPluginNodeResolve({ jsnext: true, main: true }),
            plugins.rollupPluginIncludepaths({ paths: [paths.dev + '/script/'] })
        ]
    })

    return stream
        .on('error', e => {
            console.error(e.stack);

            notifier.notify({
                title: 'Rollup error',
                message: e.stack
            });
            stream.emit('end');
        })
        // Error handling
        .pipe(plugins.plumber())
        // Prepare files for sourcemap
        .pipe(plugins.vinylSourceStream('app.js', paths.dev + '/script/'))
        .pipe(plugins.vinylBuffer())
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        // Convert ES6
        .pipe(plugins.babel({ presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }))
        // Write sourcemap
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmp + '/script/'))
        .pipe(plugins.browserSync.stream());
});
```

#### Codebase:

https://github.com/alexplummer/framework-react/blob/master/_dev/script/app.js

Comment: Did you export App class?

Comment: Have you tried instead `document.getElementById('main'),` with a `<div id="#main"/>` in your `index.html` ? Otherwise, your code looks correct.

Comment: Yes the selector is fine, same issue with or without id.

Comment: Can you try adding props in your `constructor(props)` and when calling `super(props)` ?

Comment: You forgot to `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom`.

Comment: I have added ReactDOM in there as well, no change, also this is just a test in one file, so no export of class needed.

Comment: Did you look at the call stack? The third entry from the top should be where the function is called.

Comment: @FelixKling the second entry calls at the top of the App class.

Comment: I had updated my comment already.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that cahnge, the top call is against the React '_createClass' method as injected by Babel I believe to the top of the file.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that change, the top call references '_classCallCheck' within the '_createClass'. I guess this is a Babel issue..

Comment: Apologies for reaching out but does anyone have any further suggestions? Have been crawling every reference of this error online and no luck.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Somehow your class constructor is called without `new`. You should look at the transpiled code and the call stack to find out where this is happening. Then you can try to figure out why. I guess Michael did that work for you.

Comment: @FelixKling The first thing I did was to go through the whole stack, I guess my knowledge of this is limited, thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your JSX is not transpiled correctly. If you look at the output in the devtools (second error from the bottom in the stack trace), you'll see that the class is called as a regular function:

```
reactDom.render(App(), document.querySelector('#app'));
//              ^^^^^
```

You are using `rollup-plugin-jsx` and it seems to handle that differently. There is really no reason to use this, if you are using Babel anyway, since Babel can transpile your JSX as well. I'd assume that you have added this, because Rollup was complaining about JSX. That's because your build pipeline is not quite right. You currently bundle the code with Rollup first, then you run Babel over it.

You can integrate Babel directly into Rollup with [`rollup-plugin-babel`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel), so everything that is bundled by Rollup will automatically be transpiled by Babel. By adding this plugin you can remove `rollup-plugin-jsx` entirely and you also don't need to pipe it to Babel afterwards.

These are the changes to `tasks/js.js` (Stack Overflow doesn't have syntax highlighting for git diffs, but you can see the highlighted version in the [Gist - `tasks/js.js` diff](https://gist.github.com/jungomi/7125cf2ede227a44554ac9559aa00f7b)):

```
diff --git a/tasks/js.js b/tasks/js.js
index 0caabc1..7c5319d 100644
--- a/tasks/js.js
+++ b/tasks/js.js
@@ -70,7 +70,10 @@ gulp.task('js', () => {
                name: 'app',
                plugins: [
                        plugins.rollupPluginReplace({'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'development' )}),
-                       plugins.rollupPluginJsx({ factory: 'React.createElement' }),
+                       plugins.rollupPluginBabel({
+                               exclude: 'node_modules/**',
+                               presets: [['es2015', { modules: false }], 'react']
+                       }),
                        plugins.rollupPluginCommonjs({}),
                        plugins.rollupPluginNodeResolve({ jsnext: true, main: true }),
                        plugins.rollupPluginIncludepaths({ paths: [paths.dev + '/script/'] })
@@ -93,8 +96,6 @@ gulp.task('js', () => {
                .pipe(plugins.vinylSourceStream('app.js', paths.dev + '/script/'))
                .pipe(plugins.vinylBuffer())
                .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
-               // Convert ES6
-               .pipe(plugins.babel({ presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }))
                // Write sourcemap
                .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmp + '/script/'))
```

Note that you need to turn off module transpilation in Babel, because Rollup needs ES modules. On a side note, `babel-preset-es2015` is deprecated in favour of `babel-preset-env`, which contains everything that the `es201x` presets did and more. It is a drop-in replacement for `es2015`, for details see [Migration guide from es2015 to env](https://babeljs.io/env).

Comment: I had the same issue, but it wasn't Babel that forgot to say `new App()`...it was me.